# How can I disable specific "structural warnings" that Chrome prints in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the most recent Chrome update of my browser (`64.0.3282.140`), Chrome has started spitting out yet more HTML structural warnings, specifically now:

```
[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes ...
```

These warning may not be new to Chrome, the Stripe checkout library recently changed so perhaps these structural issues were introduced by the Stripe team.  Either way there's not much I can do about it and I'm tired of mentally filtering these messages.

Here's a screenshot of my console window now, even with the "collapse" logic for similar console messages - my console now contains more opinions from Chrome than it does log messages from my application.

[image: A console window full of Chrome HTML structure warnings]

I don't want to see these specific messages at all - but I don't want to filter all warnings.

**Is there any way I can control those specific Chrome messages about "passive event listener" and "input elements should have autocomplete"?**

Comment: At the moment I think the only filter you have is right click the message and filter out all messages from particular script or use the filter text box and provide a regexp: https://superuser.com/a/995289/254309

Comment: Right click filtering won't work because the stripe autogenerates the names.  Writing a regex might work I suppose, but then I'd need to paste it in there every time. Ick - easier to just use Firefox if it comes down to that kind of thing.

Comment: If they're coming from code you don't control, then you can't control whether they show up.

Answer (score 1):

Change `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="foo"` for every `<input>` element and all warnings in the console should disappear.